# URL Rewrite GET parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want my url to look like the following

**www.website.com/home&foo=bar&hello=world**

I only want the first get parameter to change

However the actual "behind the scenes" url is this

**www.website.com/index.php?page=home&foo=bar&hello=world**

All tutorials I find change all of the parameters.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: You're expected URL is invalid. It can at most be home?foo=... because there has to be a `?` to separate path and query string.

Comment: That would also work for me, but I do not know how to do it

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Add this to your `.htaccess` in your web root `/` directory

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^home$ index.php?page=home&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
```

If you want this to work for all pages i.e. `/any-page` gets served as `index.php?page=any-page` then use

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # not a dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # not a file
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
```

---

## How do these rules work?

A `RewriteRule` has the following syntax

```
RewriteRule [Pattern] [Substitution] [Flags]
```

The *Pattern* can use a regular expression and is matched against the part of the URL after the hostname and port (with the `.htaccess` placed in the root dir), but before any query string.

#### First Rule

The pattern `^home$` makes the first rule match the incoming URL `www.website.com/home`. The `%{QUERY_STRING}` simply captures and appends anything after `/home?` to the internally substituted URL `index.php?page=home`.

The flag `NC` simply makes the rule non case-sensitive, so that it matches `/Home` or `/HOME` as well. And `L` simply marks it as last i.e. rewriting should stop here in case there are any other rules defined below.

#### Second Rule

This one's just more generic i.e. if all of your site pages follow this URL pattern then instead of writing several rules, one for each page, we could just use this generic one.

The `.*` in the pattern `^(.*)$` matches `/any-page-name` and the parentheses help capture the `any-page-name` part as a `$1` variable used in the substitution URL as `index.php?page=$1`. The `&` in `page=home&` and `page=$1&` is simply the separator used between multiple query string field-value pairs.

Finally, the `%{QUERY_STRING}` and the `[NC,L]` flags work the same as in rule one.

Comment: explanation would have been nice

Comment: @xcy7e Explanation added :)

Comment: very comprehensive , thanks