# How to rewrite URL that contain parameters?

Tags: php, .htaccess

If user access this URL(`http://domain.com/products/view-product.php?productID=21`) in browser, it should show the page `http://domain.com/new/view-product.php?pID=21`

I have tried bellow code but it wont working, so please help me to resolve.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} products/view-product.php 
RewriteRule ^products/view-product.php?productID=21$ new/view-product.php?pID=21 [R=301,L]
```

products/view-product.php are physically exists in the server, still i want to rewrite it to the new page that i have designed now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [URL Rewrite GET parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18162686/url-rewrite-get-parameters)

Comment: @umka No its not duplicating... the old url and directory and files are exists, still i want to rewrite it to new url.

Comment: have a look in the website, it will help you understand more about RewriteRule `https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't match against the query string (everything after the `?`) in a rewrite rule. Only the URI is used to match against that regular expression. You need to use the condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} products/view-product.php\?productID=21($|\ |&)
RewriteRule ^products/view-product.php$ /new/view-product.php?pID=21 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply... its not working... products/view-product.php are physically existing in server.

Comment: @rkaartikeyan doesn't matter if it exists or not. The condition says it has to exist for the rule to work. It also has to be **the first rule**. The rewrite engine processes a request before it is mapped to a file, this all happens regardless if that file exist or not.

Comment: :( i dont have a luck :S

Comment: i have found one small bug... i fixed and its works :) thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can match query string using `RewriteCond` and `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable. Query string params didn't get to `RewriteRule`.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^productID=21$
RewriteRule ^products/view-product\.php$ /new/view-product.php?pID=21 [R=301,L]
```

Or if you want to redirect all productID's:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^productID=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^products/view-product\.php$ /new/view-product.php?pID=%1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Try to disable temporarily any other rewrite directives.

Answer (score 0):

GET the value of productID and then redirect to the new URL.