# RedirectRule with conditions in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

So far I have learnt `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ index.php?page=$1`

Problem 1: How do I parse the url parameters as they are after a point certain point?

E.g. I want this page `http://example.com/index.php?page=X&id=2&err=10` to appear as `http://example.com/X/?id=2&err=10`. Given that the parameters `id` or `err` necessarily do not exists. They may or may not be present with others.

Problem 2: For some specific pages suppose `page=A` or `page=B`, if `id` exists, there will be a third parameter as well.

E.g. I want this page `http://example.com/index.php?page=A&id=10&name=Abe` to appear as `http://example.com/A/Abe/10/` and `http://example.com/index.php?page=A&id=10&name=Abe&err=101` to appear as `http://example.com/A/Abe/10/?err=101`

**Edit 30 Jan, 16**

Ok. After much searching I found that it could be implemented by using `{QUERY_STRING}`. But when I place `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]` in my htaccess my Ajax goes haywire. I want this working to implement only for index.php and no other pages.

[URL Rewrite GET parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18162686/url-rewrite-get-parameters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using RewriteCond rule I was able to solve problem 1, however, I am yet to implement it for problem 2.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
```

Solved Problem 2 as well:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^A/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ index.php?page=A&id=$1&z=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^B/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ index.php?page=B&id=$1&z=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
```

Note: For some reason using this (below) lines caused the mess. Removing the comment from them works fine.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # not a dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # not a file
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
```