# cms without view template inside url

Tags: php

I'm creating a simple, wordpresslike cms and keep all parts of a page in a table and load them using a template page named `view.php` following by a $_GET variable, for example:

```
sky.com/view.php?article=how-to-do-something
```

But as I can see on wordpress sites there is no 'view.php' template file and `$_GET` variables inside url. There is pure domain name and title of an article.

I suppose this is a better approach for SEO engines.

What is the general way to do this and how can I use the same. Is there a function to create a file on fly, or maybe a hidden file system...

The same is with `stackoverflow.com`. There is no view template inside url, but I'm rather sure it uses database table for storing parts of a page.

I tried with .htaccess file and [this accepted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18162686/url-rewrite-get-parameters) but got the error 500 - internal server error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL Rewrite GET parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18162686/url-rewrite-get-parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By way of explanation; what `stackoverflow.com` probably does is something like this:

URL:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44654672/cms-without-view-template-inside-url
```

Actual URL is first rewritten using `mod_rewrite` so that 1) the missing `.php` is added, and 2) the GET parameters are set:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^questions/([0-9]+) questions.php?qid=$1 [NC,L]
```

And so the `questions.php` page loads the question with id 44654672.

The above mod_rewrite says: take the URL, starting with `questions/` and send that URL to `questions.php`, as well as saying: After questions/ take the number value and use that as the question id GET variable so that the PHP page loads the correct question from the database.

The wording in the URL is purely for SEO purposes.

---

You will notice that `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44654672` will also load your question correctly (*), but if you change the number value (even while keeping the words the same, ( such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44351172/cms-without-view-template-inside-url ) *another* question will be loaded from the database.

- *Putting the exact URL link into my answer makes it display the question title rather than URL*

Think of it as the `mod_rewrite` is doing a ***find and replace*** search on the URL string. That's all.

Comment: Thanks, Martin. You helped me a lot.