# I want to remove query string variable and replace it query value in php

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

```
$url = example.com/your-new-key-is.php?key=5&submit=success
```

The above url consists query string and submit value, also it's not user friendly

Once I click the submit the new url want to be like that

```
$url = example.com/your-new-key-is-5/
```

I want to replace the key url with value(5) and truncate the part followed `&` symbol.

Anybody knows the answer ?

Comment: I think you might want to look into .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

You need to use mod rewrite. There are ways to write them. You can also use a rewrite rule generator to understand how its done.

Below are the rules that needs to go into the `.htaccess` file

```
# Rewrite --- example.com/your-new-key-is.php?key=5&submit=success => example.com/your-new-key-is-5/

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)key=5($|&)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)submit=success($|&)
RewriteRule ^example\.com/your-new-key-is\.php$ /example.com/your-new-key-is-5/?&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Here is a link to the Generator.

```
http://www.visiospark.com/mod-rewrite-rule-generator/
```

After you've written the rule to htaccess, you will enter in `example.com/your-new-key-is-5/` which is equivalent to `example.com/your-new-key-is.php?key=5&submit=success`

Comment: i have loaded nearly 150 numbers with in select box. The user will select the value from the list and click submit. The process is dynamic, so i want the dynamic method

Comment: you can do this by looking at this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18162686/url-rewrite-get-parameters

Answer (score 0):

I think you can:

```
$url1 = example.com/your-new-key-is.php?key=5&submit=success

$url2 = example.com/your-new-key-is-5/

<?php
$url= str_replace($url1 , $url2);
?>
```

You can see more examples here: [function.str-replace.php](http://php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: the key value will be generated dynamically. you're saying the static method.