# URL Rewrite with GET parameters

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

My aim is to redirect the following pages from/to:

```
/ -> /util/master.php?view=home # default site
/contact -> /util/master.php?view=contact # site
/contact?a=1&b=2 -> /util/master.php?view=contact&a=1&b=2 # site with params
/res/style.css -> /res/style.css # don't redirect files
```

My current rewrite script is as follows, but it will always give me an error 500.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # not a file
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ util/master.php?view=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
```

(as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18162686/url-rewrite-get-parameters,#answer-18162822))

edit: also, it should be able to work with "sub pages":

```
/contact/form?a=1&b=2 -> /util/master.php?view=contact/form&a=1&b=2 # sub page with params
```

Comment: Try checking the apache error log, it may've some info about the 500 error. The rewrite rule seems fine.

Comment: D:/Documents/xampp/htdocs/test/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters, referer: http://test.local/avasadsd

Comment: removing the comment and the space did resolve this. thanks!